# How to set up onClick functionality with react to an external website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props

So I've been setting up my portfolio, as a jr fullstack web developer. I've ran into a little trouble with react and an onClick link to an external website(my github.) I've got a card where I've passed it a {link} prop, or atleast I think that's how I've set it up lol. The goal is to set up my card to where when you click on it, it takes you to my github / hosted projects. Any advice/ guidance is greatly appreciated.

[This is my card where I want to be able to click and redirect users to my github / hosted projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKr4f.png)

[This is where I've set up my {link} prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLu8C.png)

[This is my list of projects where I map through the array and display my cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOdXq.png)

Comment: Can you please describe what the problem you're experiencing is? You just said "you ran into a little trouble" but not sure what that means.

Comment: What's the exact behavior you're experiencing when you click the link? If you inspect the element when it renders, is the href attribute set to what you expect it to be?

Comment: I still dont get it what do you want. but I see your [Product component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKr4f.png), you already have a `<a>` tag that able to redirect to a link. may you want wrap them all with `<a>` tag, so when you click the card, it will redirect you to link that you pass as props.

Comment: Sorry guys, been stressing over this the whole weekend, looks like it finally got to me lol. But whenever I click on the card nothing happens. I've passed the link on as a prop to the card, yet I get nothing. Just curious if I need to declare an onClick function or if I'm already on the right track.

Comment: Both your img and alt are empty. so what r you supposed to display on the link?

Comment: I had taken the image out because of fitment issues, but I did do that before testing the functionality of the a tag. I'll put it back in today and try that, thank you guys for the responses!

Comment: PeterT that was the issue, thank you, thank you!